# Leaflet in R not showing variable circle colors

Tags: r, leaflet

After perusing the [Intro to Leaflet](http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/), I tried to work with a dataset, but kelp getting no color for circles or markers when I attempted to use the formula interface. I've recreated a toy example, and, as you can see, something is off. Although it might be me!  So:

```
library("leaflet")
set.seed(100)
pdf <- data.frame(Latitude = runif(100, -90,90), Longitude = runif(100, -180,180))

#just red
leaflet(pdf) %>% addTiles()  %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = ~ Latitude, lng = ~ Longitude, color= "red")
```

Works just fine with a nice map showing red circle markers.

[image: Red map]

But. Adding color seems to bork the markers entirely.

```
#let's add some color!
pdf$Study <- factor(rep(1:10,10))
cols <- rainbow(length(levels(pdf$Study)))
pdf$colors <- cols[unclass(pdf$Study)]

leaflet(pdf) %>% addTiles()  %>%
  addCircleMarkers(lat = ~ Latitude, lng = ~ Longitude, color= ~ colors)
```

[image: This should be colorful]

An inspection of the colors column of pdf shows that all should be bright and beautiful, and yet, alas.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `rainbow` returns colors in `#RRGGBBAA` format, which Leaflet can't use. If you add the argument `alpha=NULL` then it should work fine.

Comment: Is this only true for the R default color functions, or is there a fix for other color palettes. For example, say I was using RColorBrewer or the wesanderson library - would I need to fix those colors as well, and is there a standard fix?

Comment: For RColorBrewer, I recommend you use the various `colorXXX` arguments included with the leaflet package, and just pass the name of the colorbrewer palette as the `palette` argument. See the examples here: http://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html But in answer to your question, RColorBrewer returns `#RRGGBB` colors so it should work fine... I'm not sure about wesanderson but I would imagine it does the same.